# How to make node in tiptap to can add place another node inside

Tags: javascript, tiptap, prose-mirror

This code works but absolutely no effect (node not created)

```
const PageNode = Node.create({
  name: 'PageNode',
  // content: 'block+',
  content: 'inline*',
  marks: '_',
  
  inline: true,
  group: "inline",
  draggable: true,

  code: true,
  isolating: true,
  defining: true,
  // draggable: true
  defaultOptions: {
    HTMLAttributes: {
      class: 'page pagebreak',
    },
  },
```

This code throws an error

```
const PageNode = Node.create({
  name: 'PageNode',
  // content: 'block+',
  content: 'block+',
  marks: '_',
  
  inline: false,
  group: "block",
  draggable: true,

  code: true,
  isolating: true,
  defining: true,
  // draggable: true
  defaultOptions: {
    HTMLAttributes: {
      class: 'page pagebreak',
    },
  },
  addAttributes() {
    // Return an object with attribute configuration
    return {
      class: {
        default: 'page pagebreak',
      },
    }
  },
  parseHTML() {
    return [
      {
        tag: 'div',
        preserveWhitespace: 'full',
      },
    ]
  },
  renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    return ['div', mergeAttributes(this.options.HTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes), 0]
  },
  addCommands() {
    return {
      setPage: attributes => ({ commands }) => {
        return commands.setNode('PageNode', attributes)
      },
      togglePage: attributes => ({ commands }) => {
        return commands.toggleNode('PageNode', 'PageNode', attributes)
      },
    }
  },
})
...
```

[error while need to place node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZshL.png)

```
<button @click="editor.chain().focus().togglePage().run()" :class="{ 'is-active': editor.isActive('PageNode') }">
    toggle page
</button>
```

Maybe I lost important parameter?

I was check TableCell node as example, works fine, but I failed to perform the same functionality in my code